# print the diagonal pettern in PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

hy i want to print diagonal pattern ini PHP, the output like bellow

[image]

this is my code

```
  for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) 
{ 

    // Loop denoting columns 
    for ($j = 0; $j < 7; $j++)  
    { 


        if ($i == 0 || $j == 0 || $i == $j ||  
            $i == 7 - 1 || $j == 7 - 1 ||  
            $i + $j == 7 - 1) 
            echo "#&nbsp;"; 
        else
            echo "&nbsp;"; 
    } 
      echo "<br>"; 
}
```

but i get output like this

[image]

the output is look different,, where my code is wrong ??

thanks

Comment: Just remove `&nbsp;` from `#&nbsp;`. See here https://3v4l.org/uUPnb

Comment: it just looks broken since its rendered in the html, use a pre tag or css :p

Comment: see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-print-hollow-rectangle-or-square-star-patterns/)

Comment: @Bian Also add 2 `&nbsp;` in your else condition. When doing such problems, try the console and not the browser, because browser is a more complicated application which renders the text according to the page font etc. Sometimes, you might also find some plugins affecting your output display on the browser. So, use console. Just open cmd, go to the path where your file is and do `php your_file_name.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You enter # with space (2 characters) VS space alone (1 char). You have two alternatives to change code:

```
    ...
        echo "#&nbsp;"; 
    else
        echo "&nbsp;"; 
    ...
```

either to (2 characters):

```
    ...
        echo "#&nbsp;"; 
    else
        echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;"; 
    ...
```

or to (1 character):

```
    ...
        echo "#"; 
    else
        echo "&nbsp;"; 
    ...
```